# Using getchar() when initial user input is "\n" C

Tags: c, getchar

When setting a character value to specified user input using the getchar() method, the user could potentially decide to not input anything, but still hit the enter key. Is there a way to check to see if the character value is "\n"?

```
// for example:

printf("input y/n\n"); 
char inp; 

// the user hits enter before entering any value
inp = getchar();
getchar();

while (inp != 'y' && inp != 'n') {
    inp = getchar(); 
    getchar(); 
}

if (inp == 'y') {
    printf("+\n"); 
} else {
    printf("-\n"); 
}
```

> ### example input/output
>
> **case 1**
>   'enter'
>   yy
>  *results in:* +
>   **case 2**
>   'enter'
>   y
>   y
>   yy
>  *results in:* +
>   **case 3**
>   'enter'
>   y
>   'enter'
>   y
>  *results in:* +

Would anyone be willing to explain these cases? As someone who is new to c, but relatively experienced in java, I'm curious to understand the uses and logic of getchar().

Comment: Compare the character you read with `'\n'`? Also note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an *`int`* (this is actually important).

Comment: Your case 3 does not seem to agree with what your code is actually doing.  I would expect the sequence `ENTER` `y` `ENTER` `y` to stay in the `while` loop.

Comment: *Is there a way to check to see if the character value is "\n"?*. That's the simple part. You just use `if ( inp == '\n' )`. The question for you is: what do you want to do when you encounter that? You haven't explained that.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks, checking to see if the character value = '\n' took care of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the second getchar()

```
// the user hits enter before entering any value
inp = getchar();
//getchar();  // this getchar() is not needed
```

also in

```
 while (inp != 'y' && inp != 'n') {
    inp = getchar();
    //  getchar(); // this getchar() is not needed
   }
```